# How do I create forms in Rasa 2.0.2?

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I cannot seem to get forms to work in Rasa 2.0.2
I am new to Rasa, so please give me a step-by-step guide on how to fix it.
I didn't create any actions nor did I create any endpoints.
Thank you so much!
I am trying to create a form to save travel data to help the user in multiple areas, for instance if the user doesn't have a place to go, then the whole conversation would be the chatbot suggesting places to the user and what's special about them, when the user decides on a place, the conversation would change to "alright what's your budget, how long, etc..."

EDIT: Managed to fix this error by changing the name of the utterance that is uttered when the form is activated to "utter_ask_entity_name" the domain file. Apparently the utterance needs the name of the entity to be activated.

```
ERROR    rasa.core.nlg.interpolator  - Failed to fill utterance template 'Your travel type is: {travel_type_slot}'. Tried to replace 'travel_type_slot' but could not find a value for it. There is no slot with this name nor did you pass the value explicitly when calling the template. Return template without filling the template.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\addal\anaconda3\envs\installingrasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\nlg\interpolator.py", line 28, in interpolate_text
    text = text.format(values)
KeyError: 'travel_type_slot'
```

EDIT 2: Fixed this error by adding `slots: slot_name: type: text` to my domain file!

```
rasa.shared.core.trackers  - Tried to access non existent slot 'travel_type_slot'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you include what you created so far it would be easier to assist with your issue.

The best way to get started is to download the project from the rasa 2 playground, found [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/playground/).

It includes a Form.